# Unfortunately, your computer does not support hardware accelerated virtualization. in ubundu 14.04

Tags: android

Unfortunately, your computer does not support hardware accelerated virtualization.
Here are some of your options:
 1) Use a physical device for testing
 2) Develop on a Windows/OSX computer with an Intel processor that supports VT-x and NX
 3) Develop on a Linux computer that supports VT-x or SVM
 4) Use an Android Virtual Device based on an ARM system image
   (This is 10x slower than hardware accelerated virtualization)

Answer (score 2):

Either your device has HAXM turned off in the BIOS, or the CPU doesn't support HAXM.  In the first case, go into BIOS and turn it on.  In the second, you can't use the emulator and have to use the much, much slower emulator (I suggest sing a real device rather than that, that's how slow it is).